# Adding rows to existing Excel file

Tags: python, pandas, pandas.excelwriter

I am trying to add a DataFrame to rows below existing cells on an existing .xlsx file with this code:

```
book = load_workbook(r"C:\path\file_name.xlsx")
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(r"C:\path\file_name.xlsx", engine='openpyxl')
writer.book = book
writer.sheets = {ws.title: ws for ws in book.worksheets}
contract_df.to_excel(writer, startrow = 10, header = False, 
sheet_name='UsrLeaseContract')
writer.save()
```

I manage to add the data, but I am getting the following error when re-opening the file:

> Removed Part: /xl/styles.xml part with XML error.  (Styles) HRESULT 
>   0x8000ffff Line 1, column 0. Repaired Records: Cell information from
>   /xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml part

and the detailed XML

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
    <recoveryLog xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main"> 
    <logFileName>error344800_01.xml </logFileName>
    <summary>
     Errors were detected in file 'C:path\file_name.xlsx'
    </summary>
    <removedParts><removedPart>Removed Part: /xl/styles.xml part with XML error.  (Styles) HRESULT 0x8000ffff Line 1, column 0.
    </removedPart>
</removedParts><repairedRecords><repairedRecord>Repaired Records: Cell information from /xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml part</repairedRecord>
    </repairedRecords></recoveryLog>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using openpyxl directly to append the data?
Ran this code and it ran without problems. Also, did not get any warnings when opening the Exel file.

```
from openpyxl import Workbook, load_workbook
from openpyxl.utils.dataframe import dataframe_to_rows
import pandas as pd

# list of strings
vegetables = ['potatoes', 'carrots', 'cabbage']

# Calling DataFrame constructor on list
df = pd.DataFrame(vegetables)

wb = load_workbook('file_name.xlsx')
ws = wb['UsrLeaseContract']

for r in dataframe_to_rows(df, index=True, header=True):
    ws.append(r)

wb.save('file_name.xlsx')
```

Comment: It worked very well and with fewer lines of code than my original code, so it is a good answer. The error is still present on my exported sheet but I realize the error is the aspect of the import file. openpyxl scraps away all formatting.